# Trouble reading and writing to files in C

Tags: c, file, file-io, struct, int

I have written the following code (as part of ab assignment for university) in an attempt to save 1 int to a text file (using fprintf) and an array of structs of type Flight to a .bin file. It seems that both are remaining empty. I am calling the read at the beginning of the program and the write on exit or when the Save option is selected. The read must first take the int value as it is a crucial counter for how many elements there are (and therefore how many need to be read / written).

I have looked at other answers, and even based some of my code off them however after reading and re-reading I still could not find a solution hence i posted a new question.

This is the Write Section, The files are flyC.txt (to store the counter) and fly.bin to store the array of structs.

```
    void writeFlight (){
    FILE * cpt;

    if ((cpt = fopen("flyC.txt", "wb")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR: Flight Count File Could Not Be Opened / Written To \n");
    }

    fprintf(cpt, "%d", curFly); 

    FILE * fpt;

    if ((fpt = fopen("fly.bin", "wb")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR: Flight File Could Not Be Opened / Written To \n");
    }

    fwrite(flyList, curFly * sizeof(struct Flight), 1, fpt);
    fclose(fpt);
}
```

And here is the Read section.

```
void readFlight(){
    //First Read file with variable curFly
    FILE * cpt;
    if((cpt = fopen("flyC.txt", "rb")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR: Flight Count File Could Not Be Opened\n");
    }

    if (1 != fscanf(cpt, "%d", &curFly)){
        printf("ERROR: Flight Count File Could Not Be Read\n");
    }

    fclose(cpt);

    FILE * fpt;
    if((fpt = fopen("fly.bin", "rb")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR: Flight File Could Not Be Opened / Read\n");
    }

    fread(flyList, sizeof(struct Flight) * curFly, 1, fpt);

    fclose(fpt);
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If you look at the files yourself (ie in notepad or similar), do they have any content?  (In other words: is the problem reading or writing?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see several issues here.

1. I understood that flyC.txt was supposed to contain plain ASCII text rather than binary data. If this is the case, than you shouldn't use `"wb"` when opening `cpt` for writing, but just `"w"`
2. While writing `cpt` you don't close it. The OS might close it for you at the end of the program, but you shouldn't rely on this.
3. While reading the file back, you've done a similar mistake for flyC.txt; you shouldn't open it using `“rb"` but just `"r"` if it contained binary data.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot `fclose(cpt);` in the write function.

Also you should return on error and not call fread/fwrite.

Comment: Thanks! It now works like a charm, I added the fclose and made it so as not to open the filee if an error occurs... Very helpful and fast